# Push Objects Key in Array when Value is True

Tags: javascript

My object look like this

```
{
 Key1: true,
 Key2: false,
 Key3: false,
 Key4: true
}
```

How to save the Keys which are true in an Array like this:

```
["Key1", "Key4"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get keys with `Object.keys()` and then use `filter()`

```js
var obj = {
  Key1: true,
  Key2: false,
  Key3: false,
  Key4: true
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(e => obj[e] === true);
console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the keys.

```js
var object = { Key1: true, Key2: false, Key3: false, Key4: true },
    trueKeys = Object.keys(object).filter(k => object[k]);

console.log(trueKeys);
```

Comment: I would suggest not using implicit type-casting. Use strict comparison instead: `filter(k => object[k] === true)`. It will only catch `true` values.

Comment: op has only `true`/`false` values. why strict comparison if truty works?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

```
var myObject = {
 Key1: true,
 Key2: false,
 Key3: false,
 Key4: true
}

var myFilteredArray = myObject.keys().filter(function(key) { return myObject[key] }

console.log(myFilteredArray); // ["Key1", "Key4"]
```

**explaination**

- myObject.keys() returns the keys of the object as an array.
- The Array filter function receives a function that is executed for each element, if that function returns true, that element is selected. The resulting array is composed of only items that have been "selected"

Answer (score 1):

```js
var keys = {
 Key1: true,
 Key2: false,
 Key3: false,
 Key4: true
}

var filteredKeys = [];

for(var key in keys) {
  if(keys[key] == true) {
    filteredKeys.push(key);
  }
}
console.log(filteredKeys);
```